# Insert Document containing dictionary to Cosmos DB without "Key" and "Value" keywords

Tags: .net, serialization, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to insert to Cosmos DB an object that one of it's properties is of type dictionary:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Dictionary<int, int> dictionary { get; }
}
```

How it looks in Cosmos DB :

```
 {
    "id": "....",
    "dictionary": [
        {
            "Key": "-1091660161",
            "Value": [
                {
                    "Key": "-2048495519",
                    "Value": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Key": "-1842294419",
            "Value": [
                {
                    "Key": "-2048495519",
                    "Value": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Key": "1544782822",
            "Value": [
                {
                    "Key": "-2048495519",
                    "Value": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The "key" and "values" keywords takes a lot of the document storage limit. Is there a way to serialize the dictionary without them ?

How I would like it to be:

```
{
    "id": "....",
    "dictionary": [
        {
            "-1091660161":
            [
                {
                    "-2048495519": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "-1842294419": [
                {
                    "-2048495519": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "1544782822": [
                {
                    "-2048495519": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried converting the dictionary to ExpendoObject before inserting, but the result is the same (implement IDictionary<T,T>)

I also tried serializing to json string, but I would rather saving an actual json object instead of a giant string as the dictionary field.

Thanks !

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're attempting to do, as you didn't include an example of desired data shape. That said: if you remove keys and values from your array, how would you then be able to query against those arrays?

Comment: @DavidMakogon I added an example for how i would like it to be. I want to query and receive the dictionary as it was before the insert.

Comment: I saw your edit: you're now trying to use discrete values as keys - I would consider this an anti-pattern. There's no way to query discrete keys because there is no key name (well, the key name is an actual value, which varies from element to element).